# In what terminology context do functions fall under?

Tags: function, terminology

Now I understand that `Defining` is to `Types` as `Declaring` is to `Variables`. But which one (`Declare` or `Define`) do functions/procedures/methods/subroutines fall under? Or do they have their own terminology?

Comment: In C++ to name one, you can both define and declare a function (those are separate things).

Comment: IMO, that falls under declaring.  I am mostly used to PHP and if I try to write two functions/methods with the same name I get an error to the effect of `Cannot redeclare myDupedFunction() ....`

Comment: @Dukeling beat me to it.

Comment: @ close voter - how could this be "opinion based"? There's bound to be a clear fact across all languages for this terminology. The problem is many people don't understand this difference and unfortunately many also assume both are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C and C++ you can **`declare`** a function (a function prototype) like this:

```
int function(int);
```

And then you can **`define`** it later, say, at the end of the file:

```
int function(int param) {
    printf("This is the param: %d", param);
    return 0;
}
```

So you can say that functions in C and C++ can fit into the terminology of both `types` and `variables`. It depends on the language you're using too, but this how I learned it.

Comment: I can clearly see the same applied to Delphi (after some confusing trial/error observations). Essentially, `Define` does not reserve or refer to any storage memory, whereas `Declare` does. `Define` simply describes what something "looks like" whereas `Declare` reserves a pointer.